# Report on users log-in total time in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, time

I've often tried to find an answer to this, but no luck googling it yet.

I imagine an app, or script, that can total up the total time each user has been logged into the PC.

This seems trivial in Linux, but I can't see it in Windows 10.

Like:

```
UserName1 Today: 52min Yesterday: 33min Last 7 days: 256min Last 30 days: 3454min
UserName2 Today: 22min Yesterday: 13min Last 7 days: 156min Last 30 days: 2454min
```

Has anybody seen such a thing?

Comment: You just need to enable `logon auditing` using `gpedit.msc`. [More Details](https://www.howtogeek.com/124313/how-to-see-who-logged-into-a-computer-and-when/).